# Выравнивание колонок в Excel при помощи openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Есть такой код, выполняющий выравнивание ячеек определенных столбцов по центру в горизонтали:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="Результат.xlsx")
sheet = book.active
letter_list = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
for letter in letter_list:
    sheet[f"{letter}" + str(range(1, df.shape[0] + 1))].alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
book.save("Результат.xlsx")

# в данном примере - 57 строк и 7 колонок, однако "A" - не задействуется
```

Однако, в ответ мне выдаёт ошибку:

`ValueError: Brange(1, 57) is not a valid coordinate or range`

Я понимаю, что мне нужно изменить **Brange (better range)** на **стандартный range** (хотя я не уверен, что это может решить эту проблему). Как я могу это сделать или есть другой способ исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вы таким образом `sheet[f"{letter}" + str(range(1, df.shape[0] + 1))].alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")` хотели создать List comprehension?
Если вы хотите выровнить только эту область столбцов, то можно цикл записать так:

```
for letter in letter_list:
    for i in range(1, df.shape[0] + 1):
        sheet[f"{letter}{i}"].alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
```

Если вам нужно/можно полностью отформатировать данные колонки, то эдак:

```
for letter in letter_list:
    col = sheet.column_dimensions[f'{letter}']
    col.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первое предложенное вами решение полностью решило всю мою проблему!

Comment: второй вариант, где мы делаем целиком всю колонку, работает очень странно.

 / Как только мы вводим в ячейку какой то текст, он как будто бы сбрасывает все настройки до стандартного, делая ее без выравнивания / 

И без разницы до или после мы сделали это выравнивание, как будто в ячейки свои личные свойства без выравнивания сохранились / 

Как этого избежать не знаете?

Comment: @Леха Да, есть ограничения openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#columns-and-rows